# Finding the length of a curve, trouble between magnitude and integral part

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, curves, arc-length

[image]

I know you're supposed to do the integral of the magnitude of r', but how am I supposed to work with this one? Am I just supposed to try and do the integral of that whole thing ^0.5 or is there something more I can do to change it to be more manageable?

Comment: So what looks like $\tau$ and $K$ are constants?  Is that an $i$ as in the imaginary unit?

Comment: You need to differentiate $r$ first and the compute the length. The length is a scalar. I'm not sure what you ave under the $\sqrt{}$. I would expect something like $\|r'(t)\| = \sqrt{2+e^{2t} + e^{-2t}}$.

Comment: Thank you copper. End of a  long week catching up to me, can't believe i didn't even to that first. Though I'm still left with the same question of what do I do to handle the integral of all that... Unfortunately these have always been a huge week spot of me in calc. :/